# How to store a Linq query and use it later?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I'm doing a wpf App and i've got a bit of an issue i would like to ask you about.

I'm querying a database on the window level and i pass the result of the query to a method in my object like this :

Window level code :

```
payrollEmailManager.SetListOfSalariesToEmailTo(
    from Record in SqlInfo.SqlTable.T_SALs 
    where Record.EtatPaie == 3 
    select new {
        Matricule = Record.MatriculeSalarie, 
        Nom = Record.Nom,
        Prenom = Record.Prenom, 
        Email = Record.EMail });
```

This is my Method Definition :

```
public void SetListOfSalariesToEmailTo(object _ListOfSalaryToRecieveMail)
{
   ListOfSalary = _ListOfSalaryToRecieveMail;
}
```

Where `ListOfSalary` is also of type `object`.

Now here is the issue for me, I have another method where I want to go trough each record of `listofsalary` and get the information I selected in query like `Matricule` or `Email`, something like this :

```
public void SendEmail()
{
    foreach(var Salary in (dynamic)ListOfSalary)
    {
        Mail.To.Add(Salary.????
    }
}
```

I can't reference the `Nom` column or the `Email` column any advice ??

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't reference" - what happens if you try? You're using dynamic typing, so you shouldn't expect Intellisense to *suggest* anything, but if you just use the properties it *may* work. However, you'll be executing the query each time every time you call `SendEmail`. To avoid that, you may want to *materialize* the query, e.g. by calling `ToList()` at the end of it (wen you call `SetListOfSalariesToEmail`). It's not clear *why* you're doing all of this dynamically though. Why not use a suitable type that has all the information you need?

Comment: I would use a SQL DataAdapter and put results into a datatable.  Then you can pass the datatable to the rest of your code instead of using linq in this case.

Answer (score 6):

If you consider your following query:

```
var query = from Record in SqlInfo.SqlTable.T_SALs 
            where Record.EtatPaie == 3 
            select new { 
                Matricule = Record.MatriculeSalarie, 
                Nom = Record.Nom, 
                Prenom = Record.Prenom, 
                Email = Record.EMail 
            };
```

After running this line the query is not yet executed to database. Only when you materialize it (using functions like `ToList()`/`ToArray()`/`FirstOrDefault` etc.) it is actually being executed in the database and information is returned.

Therefore if you just do `SomeFunction(query);` it does not execute the query and you can store it for later execution.

However you do need to change your code a bit:

- The function should not get object but `IQueryable<T>`

  ```
  public void SetListOfSalariesToEmailTo(IQueryable<T> query)
  ```
- As you want to store the query you need to later on know the type of each item. To do so do not use an anonymous object (`new { }`) in the select. Use instead a custom object or use c# 7.0 named tuples and then the function will look like:

  ```
  var query = from Record in SqlInfo.SqlTable.T_SALs 
              where Record.EtatPaie == 3 
              select new SomeType { 
                  Matricule = Record.MatriculeSalarie, 
                  Nom = Record.Nom, 
                  Prenom = Record.Prenom, 
                  Email = Record.EMail 
              };

  public void SetListOfSalariesToEmailTo(IQueryable<SomeType> query)
  {
      ListOfSalary = query;
  }
  ```

---

You can still use `object` and `dynamic` as you did, and just access the properties, but you will not have the intellisense showing you the properties and options, as it does not know the concrete type.

Comment: @Soufiane.Ach - Did this help you solve the problem?